# Prove that if $a>0$, $b<0$, then $ab+{{b}\over {a}}<0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Can someone help me in a step-by-step way in proving this inequality relation using concepts or theorems on the properties of real numbers,

if $a>0, b<0$, then $\displaystyle ab+\frac{b}{a}<0$.

Comment: This is not an equation

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have stated "proving this inequality".

Comment: @EugenCovaci-This is an inequation!!

Comment: @Danielle Is this your homework?

Comment: @EugenCovaci It's a practice exercise.

Comment: @Danielle Quite a practice to let other solve your exercises, isn't it?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I'm only asking for help because I don't know how to answer it. I'm currently studying their suggested solutions and I'm trying to think of which theorems would support the solutions.

Comment: @Danielle,have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 5):

The addition of two negative numbers is negative. The multiplication of a negative and a positive number is negative. The reciprocal of a positive number is positive. Combine these three facts.

Answer (score 2):

Given $a>0$ and $b<0\;,$ Now we can write $\displaystyle ab+\frac{b}{a} = \frac{a^2b+b}{a} = \frac{b(a^2+1)}{a}$

Now $a>0\Rightarrow a^2+1>1.$ So $a^2+1>0$ and $b<0$

So $(a^2+1)\cdot b<0$ and $a>0$

so we get $\displaystyle \frac{b(a^2+1)}{a}<0$

Answer (score 1):

We have,

$a>0>b$

We have to prove $ab+ \frac b a<0$

$ab+ \frac b a<0$

=($a^2b+b$)/$a$

Taking b common we have,

=$b(a^2+1)$/$a$

Now as $b<0$ it is bound to be negative.As $b$ is negative the above product is also negative as product of positive and negative is always negative.(Try to prove why!).

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac{b(a^2+1)}{a}=S$,say,
Now $a^2+1>1$,and by Trichotomy theorem,
$b/a>0$ or $b/a<0$[equal to zero case is rejected]
suppose that $b/a>0$ $\implies b=(b/a)a>0$ which is a contradiction so $b/a<0$
so $S=\displaystyle \frac{b(a^2+1)}{a}<0$